# Render current/selected Element from Array.map to a Modal

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So, right now I'm getting the current Element's ID or any other property (which coming from a JSON), But I'm unable to render it inside of Modal's Section.

The entire Modal is inside of `Array.map()`, I'm getting the positive result from `console.log()`, But I'm unable to render it inside the modal's section, Here's how I'm using it.

```
  open(index) {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    });
    console.log(index);
  }


    render(){
    {
this.state.items.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                      <>
    ...
                  <Button onClick={this.open.bind(this, data.id)}>
                    Contact Us
                  </Button>
                  <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onClose={this.close}
                    closeOnBlur={true}
                  >
                    <Modal.Content>
                      <Section style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                        Current ID :
                      </Section>
                    </Modal.Content>
                  </Modal>

    }
```

When I click on Button it logs the correct ID. But when I try to render it on the Section, I'm not able to do it.

```
  currentElement(index) {
    return index;
  }
```

I figured this logic to render, But usage of this method gives the following error : 
`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

This is how I'm using the said function

```
                <Modal.Content>
                  <Section style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                    Current ID :{" "}
                    {this.currentElement.bind(this, data.id)}
                  </Section>
```

Here is a [video](https://www.useloom.com/share/d4bfd0c3953c4e619f4609ba6581310c) demonstration of what is happening, I want the same ID which is in `console.log` in the DOM

Comment: Am I correct in saying that your goal is to iterate over this.state.items and return each item into the DOM?

Comment: React is giving the right warning: you can't render a function (and Function#bind returns a function, therefore `this.currentElement.bind` returns a function). The modal is just a (DOM) element: it is either shown or not per every render, and it seems from the code that the showing/hiding works. The next step I'd suggest is to put the `this.state.items#data.id` somewhere into the component state (which happens in the `open` method), and later use it around `Modal` component in the `render`'s returned value.

Comment: @JDorrian yes, but only the current Item

Comment: @rm- Sorry, but I'm unable to completely understand the `this.state.items#data.id`

Comment: I've added the entire code for modal, if that helps

Comment: the video didn't record the console, so here is a screenshot of console. https://imgur.com/a/C8bY6F3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some data structure holding data that you want to iterate over and return into the DOM, there are several ways to achieve this.

My recommendation is looping over the data structure, converting the values into DOM elements and adding them to an array. Once the loop is complete, you can return the entire array to the DOM.

For example:

```
render(){
    return(){
        <div>{this.displayItems()}</div>
    }
}

displayItems(){
    var dom_array = [] 
    this.state.items.map(function(data, index){
        dom_array.push(<div onClick={console.log('inside forEach(): ', data, index)}>{index}</div>)
    }, this)
    return dom_array
}
```

If you are trying to save the items in a way that you can access them by id, save them to state. Depending on the values being saved a javascript object may be a good solution.

**Edit:** Based on your code, to access your values inside the modal:

```
open(data) {
    this.setState({
      show: true,
      dataId: data
    });
    console.log(data); //or whatever else you want to access
  }
this.state.items.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                      <>
    ...
                  <Button onClick={() => this.open(data.id)}>
                    Contact Us
                  </Button>
                  <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onClose={this.close}
                    closeOnBlur={true}
                  >
                    <Modal.Content>
                      <Section style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                        Current ID : {this.state.dataId}
                      </Section>
                    </Modal.Content>
                  </Modal>

    }, this)
```

Comment: Errm..I already have an Array of objects which is stored in a JSON file, and then I'm looping it through to render (see the way I'm mapping), I want to display the current ID from the loop, the actual result is, it is showing all the IDs

Comment: How are you determining which one you would like to display?

Comment: Please look at my `open()` method, I've also added a video demonstration

Comment: Are you looping over the this.state.items map for every item and returning them all to the DOM? Then if you click one of the buttons it will display the associated modal? If this is the case you may have a structural issue.

Comment: Okay, structural issue, please suggest any other way to do this

Comment: @YashKaranke The best option is to call a method from the render which creates the DOM elements, packages them into a neat array and based on the onClick() of each item can set a state which will populate the modal.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine :D, it was almost right in front of my eyes. Had 3 cigarettes to figure this out